# Java how to add items directly to a class rather than having an array object

Tags: java, arrays, class

I have an `Array` as part of a class and can add items to that, but I would like to add items directly to the Class itself. Is that possible?

```
public class Buttons {
    public Array<SimpleButton> buttons = new Array<SimpleButton>();
}
```

Then I can add items like this:

```
buttons.buttons.add(simpButton);
```

But I want to add items directly like this:

```
buttons.add(simpButton);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add an "Add" function to your class and utilize it via the class object

```
public class Buttons {
public Array<SimpleButton> buttons = new Array<SimpleButton>();

public void add(SimpleButton input){
      //Handle invalid input
      buttons.add(input);
}
}
```

So to use it you will do something like -

```
Buttons buttonObj = new Buttons();
buttonObj.add(SimpleButtonTmp); //SimpleButtonTmp -> SimpleButton Obj
```

---

Otherwise if you don't wanna go this route you can do the following -

```
public class Buttons extends Array<SimpleButton>
```

Then you can access all the functions directly

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
Buttons myButton = new Buttons();
myButton.*AnyfunctionInArray();
}
```

Comment: Ok that's an interesting workaround, but the array is still not accessible as `buttons` in any other way, it still has to be accessed as `buttons.buttons`, like for example `buttons.buttons.size`.

Comment: You can create any function that you need to prevent buttons.buttons access.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. The only way I can see to do it would be to make a function for every single array method which would obviously not be practical.

Comment: @Hasen Instead of having the `Array` as a field member, you could have `Buttons extends Array`. I wouldn't recommend this approach, but it'll give the results you're looking for. What RR_IL suggested would be the proper way of handling this: define the methods you need, then either implement the logic or delegate the logic to a field member.

Comment: @Vince Emigh Yes that's what I assumed would be required. I used `Array` and not `ArrayList` but I assume either can be extended. What kinds of problems does it cause?

Comment: Edited for what you have requested

Comment: @RR_IL So what is `ArrayList<***>` ?

Comment: @Hasen If you ever decided you wanted to change your implementation from `Array` to a `List` or `Set` later on (maybe for performance reasons, or even to fix a bug), you would be required to change the public interface, which could break existing code that relied on the previous public interface. The answer from Glains avoids this issue by hiding the underlying implementation & exposing an interface rather than a concrete implementation. However, his answer uses `List`, so it would only work if `Array implements List`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure that your class basically *acts* as `List`, you can utilize the `ForwardingList` from Guava. As the name suggests, it will forward all calls to the obtained `delegate()` instance. This way, you don´t have to implement all methods youself and can only override specific methods.

```
public class ButtonList extends ForwardingList<SimpleButton> {

    private final List<SimpleButton> delegate = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override 
    protected List<SimpleButton> delegate() {
        return delegate;
    }

}
```

Since calls are forwarded by default, you can call any regular `List` method.

```
ButtonList list = new ButtonList();
list.add(new SimpleButton());
int size = list.size(); // 1
```

However, if your class *does not act* as a `List`, i would recommend to create the required delegate methods yourself. This will hide implementation and makes future changes easier. Of course, this can be a bit of work, but modern IDEs have support the create delegate methods for you.

**References:**

- [Guava CollectionHelpersExplained](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/CollectionHelpersExplained)

Comment: Interesting. Would this work any better or differently to extending `Array` or `ArrayList` ?

Comment: In the end, it´t all about flexibility. If you are sure it will remain a `List`, chose `ForwardingList` and you can change the actual implementation later (`ArrayList`, `LinkedList`, ...) **without** the need to modify all other references since you only work with the `List`interface. If you want even more flexibility, choose `ForwardingCollection`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use **ArrayList** and extend all **ArrayList** Methods example:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Buttons extends ArrayList{
    public  ArrayList<String> buttons = new ArrayList<String>();

}
```

Main Class:

```
public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Buttons buttons = new Buttons();
        buttons.add("button 1");

        int i=0;
        while(i < buttons.size())
        {
            System.out.println(buttons.get(i));
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```